# Not able to found address using google map api but got in google map

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, knockout.js, google-api

I am using Geocode API in my project, but facing some issue in it. Some of the addresses which I can found on google maps but the Geocode API not able to found same address, it shows me the other location.

For Example, address "**93 RES LAS MESETAS,ARECIBO,PR,00612**" is pointed correctly on google maps but the same address is pass in Geocode API it shows me the other address/location with "**OK**" status.

[Google Map Url](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Residencial+Las+Mesetas/@18.4694993,-66.7480689,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x8c02e712359b9d87:0x781ef5a6d85171ec!8m2!3d18.4694942!4d-66.7458802)

[Geocode Api](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4s93%20RES%20LAS%20MESETAS%2CARECIBO%2CPR%2C00612&7sUS&9sen-US)

Comment: I get the same result on Google Maps as with the Geocoder.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue and/or more details.

Comment: @geocodezip  I found different result by using this.

[Google Map Url]
(https://www.google.com/maps/place/Residencial+Las+Mesetas/@18.4694993,-66.7480689,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x8c02e712359b9d87:0x781ef5a6d85171ec!8m2!3d18.4694942!4d-66.7458802)


[Geocode Api]( 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4s93%20RES%20LAS%20MESETAS%2CARECIBO%2CPR%2C00612&7sUS&9sen-US)

Comment: please [edit] your question to address comments (this time, I put the links above in your question), however the "Geocode API" link gives me this error: `The Google Maps JavaScript API must be downloaded directly from Google's servers. Learn more: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Geocoding API service is aimed to search street addresses rather than POIs and establishments and it returns a GEOMETRIC_CENTER result while Google Maps web site prefers a place (establishment) with name 'Residencial Las Mesetas'

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D93%2520RES%2520LAS%2520MESETAS%252CARECIBO%252CPR%252C00612

In order to get a place (similar to Google Maps) via web service you should use a Places API web service. For example a text search

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=93%20RES%20LAS%20MESETAS%2CARECIBO%2CPR%2C00612&key=MY_API_KEY`

returns "Residencial Las Mesetas" with place ID ChIJh52bNRLnAowR7HFR2Kb1Hng.

```
{
  "html_attributions":[

  ],
  "results":[
    {
      "formatted_address":"Arecibo, 00612, Puerto Rico",
      "geometry":{
        "location":{
          "lat":18.4694942,"lng":-66.7458802
        },
        "viewport":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":18.47084402989273,"lng":-66.74453037010727
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":18.46814437010728,"lng":-66.74723002989272
          }
        }
      },
      "icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
      "id":"39b3c883e86aced0eee9981289772c4d395cedbf",
      "name":"Residencial Las Mesetas",
      "place_id":"ChIJh52bNRLnAowR7HFR2Kb1Hng",
      "rating":2.3,
      "reference":"CmRbAAAAG6X6Ys1tYQoR3X43N43mB8TBiz9rIle3hwXh9QgMonegltCZLd1lXrznaWJ4bwRpCMOt3iiDIeNhD4uo54Tu45_GLj85Sf2YUsuiu98qsGOs7XADBynNsRMrewkA44OwEhD5zS5N8r0dCm2ZbR2PbyD9GhRbzt9iCN3TCjxqPN3f0NrT4mZ-tQ",
      "types":[
        "point_of_interest","establishment"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status":"OK"
}
```

I hope this helps!